# Поочередная проверка элементов массива where sql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach

Приветствую. Есть примерно такой код:

```
<?php 
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $sql = 'SELECT age FROM free_people WHERE user_id = ' .$user['id']. ' AND age > 0 ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1';
    $user_age = $db->select_first($sql);

    echo $user_age. '&nbsp;лет <br>';
}
```

В массиве $users к примеру 30 записей. То есть, в данном коде к базе будет 30 обращений. Хотелось как нибудь сделать это всё одним запросом. Ведь $user['id'] можно объединить в строку и запихнуть в WHERE IN (...), но данный вариант выведет все записи по определенному id, а мне нужна одна запись, первая отсортированная по photo_id (ORDER BY photo_id DESC).

"Проще говоря" алгоритм такой: берем id, выбираем все записи по нему, сортируем, возвращаем первую запись, берем след. id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT F.user_id, F.age
  FROM free_people F
  JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, max(photo_id) photo_id
      FROM free_people
     WHERE user_id  IN(1,2,3,4) AND age > 0
     GROUP BY user_id
  ) X
    ON F.user_id=X.user_id and F.photo_id=X.photo_id
```

В подзапросе `X` получаем максимальные `photo_id` для каждого интересующего пользователя и соединяем результат с основной таблицей еще раз, получая сами записи по данному пользователю и `photo_id`.

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84140d/2)

Answer (score 0):

Если ничего не напутал, как-то так. Смысл в том чтобы выбрать все записи, отсортировать их, а потом просто сгруппировать. Сразу сгруппировать мы не можем, тк выберется запись с случайным photo_id, а нам надо наибольший, значит делаем в 2 шага:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT p.age, p.user_id 
    FROM free_people p 
    WHERE p.user_id in (' .$userlist. ') AND p.age > 0 
    ORDER BY p.photo_id DESC) b
GROUP BY  b.user_id
```

[Онлайн-тест](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84140d/1/0)

Кстати, а почему-бы просто не взять максимальный возраст?

```
SELECT max(age), user_id
    FROM free_people  
    WHERE user_id in (' .$userlist. ') AND p.age > 0 
    GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Черт, вот вариант с максимальным возрастом прям всё упрощает. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Но если всё же говорить о теме вопроса, допустим для других условий (где не подходит функция max), то первый вариант уже был испробован ранее и результаты вышли отличные от ожидаемых.  <br/><br/>
Для проверки я добавил в выборку поле date, чтобы понять возвращается первая строка из сортировки или нет. Как оказалось возвращается запись из центра всей выборки. То есть, у определённого id есть 6 записей и в группу возвращается не первая запись, а 3 или 4 (точно не обращал внимание).

Comment: @АртёмКостенко потому-то и надо сначала отсортировать, а только потом группировать

Comment: так в Вашем варианте вроде и так сортируются, а потом добавляются в группу, но результат оказывается эквивалентный такому запросу: `SELECT age, user_id FROM free_people WHERE user_id IN (...) AND age > 0 GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: `Кстати, а почему-бы просто не взять максимальный возраст?` - потому что надо брать не максимальный возраст, а возраст где  максимальный `photo_id`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мой первый пример решает задачу?